# Android Material Design eliminates support for `android:textSize` everywhere?

Tags: android, material-components-android

Can it really be true that the material design team has summarily **DONE AWAY** with **ALL** support for setting `android:textSize` across **EVERY** material design component for Android, leaving developers with only the crippled `TextAppearance` style overrides, which only gives access to setting font style, but not size?

Can it really be true that subscribing to Material Design means loosing almost all ability to control text size across your entire app?

No matter how many variations of `materialThemeOverlay=""`, `textAppearance*=""`, etc, I attempt to set, it appears that material design components never expose text size, thus not only assuming the correct text size for every occasion (a poor idea indeed), but actually fully preventing me from making my own design choices.

Have I missed something critical in the mountain of material design docs?  Or does simply attempting to use a material design component in an Android app actually permanently lock you out of controlling your own text size?

Comment: May I ask for an example of a component that you think should have a textSize attribute? I haven't run into this issue before!

Comment: Chips, Menus, Toolbar, Date Pickers, Navigation Drawers, Snackbars, etc - basically any material design component for android that renders text.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you are right in the fact that some components don't specifically use the `android:textSize` attribute, however in most instances there is a way to change the text size.

I think that their idea with the new material design was for you to override theme attributes in your app which are in turn used by the Material Components to create a more cohesive style. You can read more about how to do this with the [Theming Guide](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/theming-overview) they have produced.

However most of the components you mentioned actually do have an easy way which I have tested:

**Chip**

This actually does respect the `android:textSize` attribute as it is a descendant of `TextView`.

**Toolbar**

These use the `app:titleTextAppearance` attribute which can point to a style using `android:textSize`.

**NavigationView**

I presume by saying "Navigation Drawers" you are referring to the `NavigationView` component which is commonly used in a navigation drawer. If so the text size of the items can be changed using the `app:itemTextAppearance` attribute which again can point to a style with `android:textSize`.

In regards to Snackbars and Date Pickers you are right that they don't seem to expose the text size of these without overriding theme attributes or changing it programmatically which is a workaround. You could submit a feature request to the Material Components team if you think these are needed.

**Edit**
Here is some the results of the simple example I have tested and the minimal code used to reproduce them.

**The layout and style definition**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:title="Toolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/BigText" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/BigText"
        app:menu="@menu/test_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chip"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<style name="BigText">

    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
</style>
```

**My results**

[image: Results]

Comment: `textAppearance` does *not* grant you access to text size with material components.  You may refer `textAppearance` to a style with `textSize` set - then watch in abject horror as that `textSize` is summarily ignored.

Comment: @rmirabelle I have tested both `Toolbar` and `NavigationView` with text appearance as I mentioned in my answer and the text size changes as expected and I will edit my answer with code that I have tested. So I am not sure whether something else is interfering in your tests?

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. I'll come back and post my own example the next time I face this, which will no doubt be shortly.